# Neo4J: Employee/Manager hierarchy

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've loaded up a csv with employee data, created labels and relationships successfully. I can run the following:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:is_over]->() RETURN p
```

and I get back clusters of Managers and employees but they are disconnected. How do I get a solid link of those relationships?

*Edit*

Here's the setup I used to define everything:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ldap.csv" AS row 
MERGE (C:Company {Company: row.company})
MERGE (N:Name {Name: row.user_name})
MERGE (M:Manager {Manager: row.manager_name})
MERGE (B:BU {BU: row.bus_unit})
MERGE (T:Title {Title: row.title})
MERGE (CC:CostCenter {CostCenter: row.cost_center})
MERGE (D:Dept {Dept: row.dept})
MERGE (E:Mail {Dept: row.mail})
MERGE (DN:DisplayName {DisplayName: row.display_name})
ON CREATE SET N.DisplayName = row.display_name,N.UserName = row.user_name,N.Mail = row.mail,N.Title = row.title,N.Dept = row.dept,N.BU =  row.bus_unit,N.Manager = row.manager_name,N.CostCenter = row.cost_center,N.Company = row.company
MERGE (N)-[:works_at]->(C)
MERGE (N)-[:has_bu]->(B)
MERGE (N)-[:has_title]->(T)
MERGE (N)-[:has_cc]->(CC)
MERGE (N)-[:works_in]->(D)
MERGE (M)<-[:is_over]-(DN);
```

Both M and DN are in the same format.

Comment: Does `RETURN nodes(p), relationships(p)` work for you?

Comment: No - same result. I get clusters of managers->employees but the managers themselves are not linked to who they report to. Is it possible my relationship and/or my data structure is incorrect? I did a simple MERGE (M)<-[:is_over]-(N); when I loaded the csv and set the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've organized your data load, a `Manager` is always over a `DisplayName`.   You don't have a full hierarchy, because a `DisplayName` is never `is_over` a `Manager`.

So it makes sense that you get a bunch of individual disconnected chains.   The `is_over` relationship always goes from a Manager to a DisplayName.

I'm assuming that the `row.display_name` gives you a name that matches to some other `Manager`.   I would consider getting rid of `DisplayName` and `Manager` and model both as just `Employee`.  Then just say `(e1:Employee)-[:is_over]-> (e2:Employee)`

Last part you're missing is that you need to ensure in your data that certain values of `display_name` match other rows values of `manager_name`.  If this is not true, then the data won't connect no matter what you do.

I'm assuming data like this:

`manager_name,display_name
A,B
B,C`

The way your load works right now, you'll get manager A is_over display name B, and Manager B is over display name C, but "display name B" and "Manager B" are different and have no connection.